# ¿Cuál es la palabra correcta, "membresía" o "membrecía"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, ortografía, rae

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de escribir la siguiente palabra: *membresía* o *membrecía*, según las normas de la Real Academia de la Lengua Española?

Según el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas de la RAE (2005)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=membrec%C3%ADa), la forma correcta de escribir la palabra (en ese entonces) era "membrecía":

> **membrecía**. En muchos países americanos, ‘condición de miembro’ y ‘conjunto de miembros’:
>
> > *«Cumplir con los criterios para obtener la membrecía en la unión monetaria económica de Europa»* (*Excélsior* [Méx.] 2.1.97);
>
> > *«El éxito con que culminó la huelga [...] favoreció el aumento de la membrecía de esa federación»* (*Gordon Crisis* [Méx. 1989]).
>
> Aunque, debido al [***seseo***](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=IIUwJDU07D6XC2xEky), está muy extendida en el uso la forma [image]*membresía*, la grafía correcta es *membrecía*, ya que el sufijo español para formar este tipo de derivados es *-cía* (de *abogado, abogacía;* de *clero, clerecía*); la terminación *-sía* es propia de los sustantivos derivados de nombres o adjetivos que terminan en *-s: burguesía* (de *burgués*), *feligresía* (de *feligrés*).

Comment: Es la primera vez que leo "membrecía".

Comment: la corrección en el lenguaje tiene mucho que ver con la forma correcta de pensar, creo que estaría bien escribir y decir membresía, a mi personalmente, me recuerda a ambrosía.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ambas son correctas. Membresía es la palabra original. Membrecía no estuvo registrada hasta la edición 23 del diccionario RAE, sin embargo ahora figura como sinónimo de membresía.

> [**Membresía:**](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?type=3&val=membres%EDa&val_aux=&origen=RAE)
>
> 1. f. *Ec., El Salv., Guat., Hond., Méx. y Pan.* Condición de miembro de una entidad.
> 2. f. *Cuba, Guat., Hond., Méx. y Pan.* Conjunto de miembros.

En cualquier caso, se trata de un anglicismo y un americanismo, es decir, es una palabra que proviene del ingles y que solo se utiliza en el castellano de América latina.

En el castellano de España no suele utilizarse, si se utiliza, sin embargo la construcción "Ser miembro".

Por ejemplo, en América latina se utilizaría la siguiente expresión:

> Quisiera cancelar mi membresía.

Mientras que en el castellano de España se utilizaría la siguiente:

> Quisiera dejar de ser miembro.

Ambas son correctas, pero cada una debe utilizarse en su contexto. :-)

Comment: Queriendo emplear una única palabra, "afiliación" creo que es un buen sustituto.

`Quisiera cancelar mi afiliación a esta entidad.`

Answer (score 3):

La RAE reconoce ambas ortografías:

> #### [membrecía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OrBFqBR)
>
> 1. f. *Am.* [membresía.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OrBSmIC#NdLlsfn)

> #### [membresía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OrBSmIC)
>
> `Adapt. del ingl. membership.`
>
> 1. f. *Am.* Condición de miembro de una entidad.
> 2. f. *Am.* Conjunto de miembros.

Y además [los dos](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=membres%C3%ADa%2Cmembrec%C3%ADa&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3) se usaba desde la adopción de la palabra:

[image]

Según el Diccionario de americanismos, la ortografía con *-cía* se usa solo en México, Colombia y Perú:

> #### [membrecía.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=membrec%C3%ADa)
>
> **I.    1.**    *Mx, Co, Pe.* **membresía**, condición. pop.
>    **2.** *Mx, Co, Pe.* **membresía**, conjunto.

y la con *-sía* en muchas más regiones:

> #### [membresía.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=membres%C3%ADa) <sub>(Del ingl. *membership*).</sub>
>
> **I.    1.**    f. *EU, Mx, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, RD, PR, Co, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py.* Condición de miembro de una entidad. (**membrecía**).
>    **2.** *Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, RD, PR, Ch, Py.* Conjunto de miembros. (**membrecía**).
>    **3.** *ES, RD, PR.* Matrícula de una sociedad o club.

Comment: Yo había visto *membresía* en México, principalmente.