# Are there dialectal differences in spelling in Spanish?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, ortografía, rae

In some languages, there are different spelling standards in different major dialects. For example:

| British English | American English |
| --- | --- |
| colour | color |
| aluminium | aluminum |

| Catalan | [Valencian](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valenci%C3%A0#L%C3%A8xic) |
| --- | --- |
| cinqué | cinquè |
| arrencar | arrancar |

| European Portuguese | [Brazilian Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_orthography#Brazilian_vs._European_spelling) |
| --- | --- |
| anónimo | anônimo |
| óptimo | ótimo |

Are there similar examples of spelling differences in different Spanish dialects? Or is it completely standardised?

Comment: Note that the difference between words like *ótimo* and *óptimo* reflect a real difference in pronunciation. While some words are effectively bound by geographic region, it's not a perfect correspondence and may even vary by idiolect. The AO90 basically says to write the P if you say it. The same issue occurs with aluminum/aluminium, though not with color/colour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Bello orthography

From 1844 to 1927, the government of Chile, (and some other South American countries influenced by this) followed and recommended an adaptation of [Andrés Bello's revised Spanish orthography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bello_orthography):

> 1. Substituting ⟨j⟩ for "weak" ⟨g⟩ sounds (*jeneral, jinebra*)
> 2. Substituting ⟨i⟩ for ⟨y⟩ used as vowels (*rei, i*);
> 3. Writing ⟨s⟩ instead of ⟨x⟩ before consonants (*testo*).

However, the original spellings eventually regained popularity and Chile returned to following the RAE's orthography after this date.

#### Individual examples

As prm296 says there are a number of Mexican toponyms etc which use the historical "x" in place of "j"; and words which are pronounced differently in Latin America vs Spain and whose orthographies reflect this (e.g. [béisbol/beisbol](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/242/18348) etc, as well as a number with orthographies not recognised by the RAE e.g. cónyuge/[cónyugue](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3nyuge#Pronunciaci%C3%B3n)).

There is also the occasional word in seseo or yeísmo regions that has taken on a homophonic alternative spelling:

| Palabra | Alt |
| --- | --- |
| membresía | membrecía ([Mexico, Colombia, Peru](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3642/18348)) |
| jericalla | jericaya ([Mexico](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=jericaya)) |

As well as replacing hi → y, hu → gü, b/v → g, ñ → ni, ll → li:

| Palabra | Alt |
| --- | --- |
| hierra | yerra ([Argentina, Bolivia, Uruguay](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KNBlphr)) |
| huero | güero ([Mexico](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=g%C3%BCero)) |
| buey | güey ([Paraguay](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=g%C3%BCey)) |
| vomitar | gomitar ([Costa Rica, Perú, Bolivia, México, Puerto Rico, El Salvador, Colombia, Chile (rural)](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gomitar)) |
| pergeño | pergenio ([Nicaragua, Chile, Uruguay](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pergenio)) |
| buganvilla | buganvilia ([México, Guatemala, Honduras](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=buganvilia)) |

Comment: I don't think yerba/hierba is a good example. At least in Argentina, where there is a brand that sells  "yerba con hierbas". The word "yerba" is exclusively used to mean "yerba mate", while "hierba" is literally "herb".

Comment: @martinargerami ah I've misunderstood then, I'll replace the example with hierra/yerra.

Comment: I think you are mixing words there. "Hierra" is about iron (and horses!), is the first person singular of "herrar". "Yerro" (noun) means "mistake", but the verb is "errar".

Comment: @martinargerami [yerr**a**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KNBlphr), not yerro :)

Answer (score 10):

[Some may say that there are not](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-main-differences-between-spanish-in-spain-and-spanish-in-latin-amer), however there are two special cases where there are spelling differences:

- **Vídeo** (Spain) | **Video** (Latin America). [This one is due to the differences in pronunciation](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=video). Spaniards tend to stress the first syllable (VÍ-DE-O), while Latin Americans stress the second syllable (VI-DÉ-O). Both spellings are recognized by the RAE.

  - As ukemi points out, some other differences derived from different pronunciation are: buganvi**ll**a / buganvi**li**a; b**é**isbol/beisbol; **v**omitar/**g**omitar; **h**ierba/**y**erba; jerica**ll**a/jerica**y**a
- **Méjico** (Spain and Latin America) | **México** (Mexico). Now, [the RAE recommends](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=yw4cM0fJdD6eNgXK1j) the use of `x` in words like `México`, and `mexicano`. However, not so long ago, the use of `j` was pretty standard everywhere but in Mexico when spelling those words (and, as I understad, still common in some regions of Spain).

  - Similar to the last one, in Mexico there are a lot of toponyms where the use of `x` and `j` still varies from place to place. Oa**x**aca/Oa**j**aca; Te**x**as/Te**j**as; **J**alapa/**X**alapa; **X**alcomulco/**J**alcomulco; **X**ilotepec/**J**ilotepec.
  - Back in 1815, the RAE stated that all /j/ sounds must be written with a `j` instead of an `x`. For example: `Quixote` -> `Quijote`. However, in Mexico (back then, in the middle of the Independence War) this rule was never fully applied. This is why there's that particular spelling drift.

I know that it's not your exact question, but please consider that t**he dialectic drift in Spanish is heavily marked in other features of the language** (like semantics, use of pronouns, verb conjugation, pronunciation, use of foreign words), and not so much in spelling.

Comment: I don't agree that video is a spelling difference. There is a different pronunciation that obligates a different spelling. *nadás* isn't just the Argentinian spelling of *nadas*, it's pronounced differently and this spelled differently because the orthographic rules dictate it.

Comment: @guifa I think this raises the question of what counts as a different 'word' in this context. There's something of a scale: different pronunciation, same spelling (*zebra* seseo vs non-seseo) > same pronunciation, different spelling (*hierba, yerba*) > different pronunciation, different spelling (*vídeo, video*) > unrelated etymologies, same concept (*coche, auto*)

Comment: @guifa I would argue that "pronunciation induced differences" are indeed valid spelling differences worth pointing out and studying as such. Vídeo/video is a similar case to óptimo/ótimo in Portuguese (cited by OP). Irregular pronunciation forced a spelling difference in Brazil (ótimo).

Comment: Right, a true spelling difference is one that exists independent of word pronunciation. I don't think we'd say that Maria and Marie and Mary are "just spelling differences" in English: they are three separate names, even if they share a identical common origin. Méjico/México is a true spelling difference. Garage/garaje is too. Any word based on a difference between b/v, g/j, x/j would be as well as the different spelling induces no changes of phonemes, which does happen in the case of vídeo/video, aluminum/aluminium, óptimo/ótimo, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from a few words (see other posters) the spelling is identical, whereever you are. In general, you won't be able to determine the origin of a speaker by his spelling - but by the choice of words.

I think that Argentina is the only place, where you intentionally spell differently. There I could see plenty of billboards with a spelling that would be considered incorrect anywhere else. Apparently, in Argentina the root of a verb doesn't change in the imperative or other forms as it would elsewhere, e.g., "probalo" instead of "pruebalo".

Comment: In Argentina they use different verb forms, but the rules for accents are identical.  The command for "buy" is "comprá" (com-PRA) instead of "compra" (COM-pra), and so the addition of an object results in compralo (com-PRA-lo) rather than cómpralo (COM-pra-lo).  The accent rules are the same: no accent if penultimate stress and ends in vowel/n/s, or if final stress and ends in anything else, written accent otherwise on the stressed syllable.

Comment: Although it is not exactly a spelling variant, I think the answer is useful. The first time I saw mobile phone company billboard where they wrote **llamá** instead of **llama** I was still surprised even though I was fully aware of the verb forms used in Argentina.